Should we create new tag for each game?
What is our tag-policy?
Someone asked a question about a game with no tag, should I make a tag of that game?  He state that no tag exists, so he tagged board-game-geek.
Does the answer change if I suspect that the tag will have just a single question?
For reference: question about Vaults.

Yes, each game receives a tag. It's fine if there's only one entry.
However: make sure you add a tag wiki! This is not just to clarify the tag, but because if a tag has only one question and no tag wiki, the tag will get deleted by the system as and the question may become simply untagged, making the game vanish and nullifying your work creating the tag in the first place. If there's a tag wiki, this automatic removal never happens.
See this Meta.SE feature request for this behaviour: Do not expire single-use tags that have a tag wiki

Over on Arqade single use tags were set to not get auto deleted, so I imagine the same would be possible here.
